# Save string as array of floats C++

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, getline

I am receiving from terminal the following string:
"4 4 0.2 0.5 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.3 0.0 0.5"
My objective is to save this string as an array of floats like arr=[4,4,0.2,...]. I do not know the size of the array in advance so depends on what the user writes. The values are always separated by a space.

I have tried using std::stof(as in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstof-in-cpp/) , stringstream (as stated in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/) but none of them works.

Trials:

```
cout << "Introduce the transition matrix \n";
getline (cin, trans_matrix);
std::vector<float> arr(trans_matrix.size(), 0);
int j = 0, i;
// Traverse the string
for (i = 0; trans_matrix[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    // if str[i] is ' ' then split
    if (trans_matrix[i] == ' ') {
        j++;
    }
    else {
        arr[j] = std::stof(trans_matrix[i]) // string to float
    }
}
```

But the compiler says:

> No matching function for call to 'stof'

Comment: There are many ways how to do this with standard c++. I'd recommend you lookup `std::vector`, `std::back_inserter` and `std::istringstream` and how to combine this. You'll probably can do that in a single line of code. (side note: Geeks-for-geeks is a well known notoriously source of bad published code and wrong information. Just stay away from there, if you really want to learn how to program)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite mixed up. Half your code treats a string as a sequence of characters (which is correct) but the other half treats it as a sequence of floats which is not really true. For instance

```
std::vector<float> arr(trans_matrix.size(), 0);
```

this creates a vector the same size as the string. But the string size is the number of characters which is not the same as the number of floats in the string. Also

```
arr[j] = std::stof(trans_matrix[i]);
```

`trans_matrix[i]` is a character, it's not a string, so you can't use a function on it which converts a string to a float.

I'm trying to make it clear that you can't program by writing code that's approximately right. You have to think carefully about what you are doing and write code that is exactly right. You have to be completely clear and precise about the concepts.

How would you do this if you were reading from `std::cout`? Well it's exactly the same way if you are reading from a string except you use a `std::istringstream` instead of `std::cout`. Here's one straightforward way.

```
#include <sstream>

std::vector<float> arr;
std::istringstream input(trans_matrix);
float f;
while (input >> f)
    arr.pusk_back(f);
```

Simple, create a string stream, read the floats one at a time, add them to the vector.

Comment: You are telling me to do this?
    
getline (cin, trans_matrix);
std::vector<float> arr(trans_matrix.size(), 0);
std::istringstream input(trans_matrix);
float f;
while (input >> f)
    arr.push_back(f);

Because an error appears in isstringstream: 
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'

Comment: That's because you need `#include <sstream>`

Comment: You should also remove this `std::vector<float> arr(trans_matrix.size(), 0);` That is wrong.